# One-to-may and generics: "Association references unmapped class"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

**TL;DR version:** The code below gives me a "*Association references unmapped class*" exception when building the SessionFactory. What should be changed in the code to fix it?

---

Even though Ayende @ Rahien doesn't recommend using mappings to generic classes in [this 2007 article](http://ayende.com/blog/2951/nhibernate-and-generic-entities) I still had a go at it. I used the approach he mentioned. First the bit that *is* working:

```xml
<class name="Review`1[Person]" table="Review">
  <id name="Id" column="ReviewId"><generator class="native" /></id>
  <property name="Rating" />
  <many-to-one name="Subject" column="PersonId" class="Person" />
</class>
```

The corresponding generic class looks like this:

```cs
public class Review<T> : BaseEntity where T : IReviewable
{
    public virtual int Rating { get; set; }
    public virtual T Subject { get; set; }
}
```

This is working, and I can load these `Review` entities and show them in my MVC views no problem. The nice part is that my `Subject` will have the correct type when I use it in the controller and view.

---

However, when trying to map a collection of Review items on my Person class things start to break down. Here's the mapping I'm currently using:

```xml
<class name="Person">
  <!-- abbreviated -->
  <bag name="Reviews" table="Review">
    <key column="PersonId"/>
    <one-to-many class="Review`1[Person]" />
    <!-- Also tried these:
    <one-to-many class="table="Review"> 
    ... plus a few variations with fully qualified names ...
    -->
  </bag>
</class>
```

With this (abbreviated) class:

```cs
public class Person : BaseEntity, IReviewable
{
    /* Abbreviated */
    public virtual IList<Review<Person>> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

This ends with an exception while building the SessionFactory:

> **Association references unmapped class**: ....insert one-to-many.class here....

So the question: What's the problem here? Is this even possible? Should Ijust give up on mapping generic entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping-by-code generated this for me:

```xml
<class name="NHTest.Review`1[[NHTest.Person, NHTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" table="Review">
  ...
  <many-to-one name="Subject" column="..." />
</class>
<class name="Person">
  ...
  <bag name="Reviews">
    <key column="..." />
    <one-to-many class="NHTest.Review`1[[NHTest.Person, NHTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

So, try with fully-qualified names.

Comment: The Version/Culture/PublicKeyToken bit on the generic type was in fact the key. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to put up this answer!